# Making a motor turn a certain amount by a button

Tags: motor

I'm new here, so sorry for any inconvenience/misunderstanding. I want to have 4 motors that will all turn 90 degrees forward then stop on a button. Then when the same or different button is pressed, the motor will reverse 90 degrees back to the original position. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You need a servo motor to do this with a pot feedback for position.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain (1) the application, (2) what type of motors, AC or DC voltage and current or power, (3) what the buttons are - finger buttons or limit switches.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_(radio_control)

Comment: How fast, how strong?  This would be easy-peasy if the mechanical constraints could be satisfied with RC servos -- you'd just need to give them power and the proper PWM signal.

Comment: If an RC servo would work you could control it with an Arduino or a couple of IC chips (say a 555 and a 74HC00 plus a few other parts).

Answer (score 2):

For only 90 degrees of rotation, I would consider a push-pull solenoid operating a bell crank mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with end stops and micro-switches cutting power when it reaches the 90 degrees. As for turning back either have a second button powering the motor in reverse, again, switched off by a micro-switch.

Comment: Also quite commonly done with a rotary wafer cam type mechanism having  quarter circle tracks on it which complete the circuit until they rotate too far.